# Unbounded linear operator on hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Does anyone know an example of an unbounded linear operator between two Hilbert spaces? I have a hard time coming up with an example especially when most of the time one deals with bounded ones.

Moreover I want to show that any bounded linear operator between two Hilbert spaces with finite rank is compact. I can prove that but wondered what an unbounded linear operator with finite rank would look like.

My search on the internet did not yield anything.

Comment: There exist unbounded linear functionals, that is unbounded rank one maps. If you want an unbounded operator, you can construct one like this. Let $(e_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be any set of linearly independent vectors in $H$. Let $\tilde A : \mathrm{span}(\{ e_n\})\to H$ be defined by $\tilde A ( \sum_{k} a_k\ e_k) = \sum_k k a_k \ e_k$. Now extend $\{ e_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to a basis $\{ e_n\}_{n\in I}$ of $H$ (here $I$ will be some uncountable index set) and let $A(e_n)=\tilde A(e_n)$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ and $A(e_n)=0$ else.

Comment: @s.harp what do you mean by $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ linearly independent? Linear independency is a property for a collection of finitely many vectors. Do you mean that $(e_n:0\le n \le N)$ is linearly independent for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, any finite subset is linearly independent. Or in other words you cannot express any of the $e_n$ by a finite linear combination of the rest.